# Why doesn't MuPAD draw a dotted line at the discontinuity?

Tags: matlab, math, symbolic-math, piecewise, mupad

I have the initial drawing which I need to make using sums of step functions:

[image: initial drawing]

Solution:

We have 3 lines L1 ,L2 and L3
L1:

y-y1=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)(x-x1)
y-1=(3-1)/(1-0)(x-0)

```
Simplify(y-1=(3-1)/(1-0)*(x-0));

solve(y-1=2*x|x=t,y);

L1(t):=2*t+1:;

f1(t):=u0(t):;
f2(t):=-1*u0(t)|t=t-1:;
S1(t):=f1(t)+f2(t):;
L1(t):=S1(t)*L1(t):;
plot(L1(t));
```

[image: Picture 2]

and then :

```
f1(t):=3*u0(t)|t=t-1:;
f2(t):=-3*u0(t)|t=t-2:;
L2(t):=f1(t)+f2(t):;plot(L2(t));
```

[image: Step 2]

```
L1:y-y1=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)(x-x1)
Simplify(y-1=(0-1)/(3-2)*(x-2));

solve(x+y=3|x=t,y);

delete f1,f2;
L3(t):=3-t:;
f1(t):=u0(t)|t=t-2:;
f2(t):=-1*u0(t)|t=t-3:;
S2:=f1(t)+f2(t):;
L3(t):=S2(t)*L3(t):;
plot(L3(t));
```

[image: Step 3]

And the final plot:

```
L(t):=L1(t)+L2(t)+L3(t);
plot(L(t),GridVisible);
```

[image: Final]

I wonder why MuPAD doesn't show an asymptote between points (2,3) and (2,1)... is it a bug?

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to be runnable. `u0(t)` is not defines. Also what is the point of the calls to `Simplify` and `solve` without specifying return values to use? Those lines also seem to produce errors because you've not prided code to instantiate `x` and `y`. Also, are you referring to the lack of dashed lines in your last image? I don't see them anywhere there. It would probably be clearer if you turned the grid off.

Comment: My guess: they are hidden by the grid.